# Transformation of limits after variable substitution in a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Let $$f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{x y\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{3}}, & \text { if }(x, y) \neq(0,0) \\ 0, & \text { if }(x, y)=(0,0)\end{array}\right.$$Show    that $$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{1} f(x, y) d y d x \neq \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2} f(x, y) d x d y$$

I was attempting the above problem and decided to substitute.

$$\lambda=\frac{y}{x}\\x+y=t$$

I found the jacobian

$$|J|=\frac{t}{{(1+\lambda)}^2}$$

finally this transforms the integral into

$$\int_0^3\int_1^2 \frac{({(\frac{1}{\lambda}})^2-1)}{(\frac{1}{\lambda}+\lambda)^3t}d\lambda dt$$

which diverges because of the logarithmic term.

I suspect I have erred in taking the limits but i am unable to visualise the change of domain for the following transformation. It would be great if somebody could explain in detail or link anything helpful.
I have transformed the points (0,0) to (0,1), and (1,2) to (3,2) by plugging in the values of x,y into

$$\lambda=\frac{y}{x}\\
x+y=t$$

Regards.

Comment: The lowest limit for $\lambda$ is $0$, when $y=0$, and it goes to $\infty$ when $y$ is finite and $x=0$

Comment: if that was the case the integral would vanish

Comment: I don't think it does. Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\lambda^3$, and just plot that function. It is always positive, but has a vertical asymptote at $\lambda=1$

Comment: Try to use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known example of a [Function where changing the order of integration is not allowed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765090/function-where-changing-the-order-of-integration-is-not-allowed?noredirect=1)

There is no need to make a change of variables. It is easy to verify that
$$\int \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3} d y=\frac{xy^2}{2(x^2+y^2)^2}+c
\;\text{and}\; \int \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3} d x=-\frac{x^2y}{2(x^2+y^2)^2}+c.$$
Therefore, the iterated double integral on the left-hand side is
$$\int_{0}^{2} \left(\int_{0}^{1} f(x, y) d y\right) d x=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx=-\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right]_0^2=\frac{1}{5}.
$$
In a similar way we show that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{0}^{2} f(x, y) d x\right) d y=-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{(4+y^2)^2}\,dy=\left[\frac{1}{4+y^2}\right]_0^1=-\frac{1}{20}.$$

Comment: Wow! What an incredible idea!! Please tell me how on earth you got this inspiration?

Comment: @LawrenceMano This is a well-known example